# A question related to decomposition of a counting argument

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am reading about square free values of quadratic polynomials:

Consider following conjecture:[[image]][

Now consider the following expression

Number of elements in the set { ${n\leq X : D| f(n) } $ }

Author writes that he is decomposing the above expression and writes it equal to

$\sum_{C mod D, f(C) =0 mod D}$ Number of elements in the set { $n\leq X : n = C mod D$}.

But I am unable to see how it will be equal to the 2nd expression.

Can you please help with that.

Comment: For any integer $n$, $D|f(n)$ iff $f(n \textrm{ mod } D)=0$, right?

Comment: @Mindlack If D | f(n) , I can say f(n) $\equiv $ 0 ( mod D) . Can you please tell how you deduced f(n mod D) =0?

Comment: @Mindlack Can you please reply?

Comment: How do you define $f(n \text{ mod } D)$?

Comment: @Mindlack Let n mod D =x , then f(n mod D) = f(x) .

Comment: So, if $D|f(n)$, then $f(n \text{ mod } D)=f(n) \text { mod } D=0 \text{ mod } D$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks!